# Nested time complexity

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity

I hope this is a simple question, but Google did not give me any immediate results.

If I have a function with running time O(n log n) and inside that function is another function, also taking O(n log n), then what is the total running time of the function?

Say I have a list of lists.

it takes n log n time to the find the desired list and then n log n time again to find the desired item within that list.

something like

```
find list in n log n time
     find element in list in n log n time
```

Is the running time still just n log n?

Thank you in advance.

What if the function looks like this:

```
for each element e1 in list                          // (O(N) time)  
    if e1 is the one we are looking for  
        for each element e2 in e1                    // (O(N) time)  
            do something
```

It is O(N) inside O(N), but the second O(N) is only executed once in the first loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how often you call the second function.

If you execute a function that finds a list within a list of lists in O(n log n) time 
and then searches *just that one list* for desired element, which it finds in O(m log m) time,
then the total running time is O(n log n + m log m).
If m=n then the total time is just O(n log n).

If the outer loop performs O(n log n) "steps", and at each step you consider one list from the list of lists and call a function that takes O(m log m) time to find a desired item in that list, then the total running time is O(mn (log m)(log n)).  I'm having difficulty imagining what application would use an algorithm like this, however.

If you execute a loop O(N) times, and during at most *one* of the iterations of the loop you execute an "inner" loop that runs in O(M) time, then the total running time of the outer loop is O(N + M).  Note that the reason we say O(M + N) is that we don't have
any other information in this paragraph about which grows faster, M or N, and O(M + N)
covers us in either case.  Again, if we knew that M=N, or even if we just knew that M is O(N) (doesn't grow faster than N), then we could just write the total time as O(N).

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you to Mooing Duck aswell. Your comment was also very helpful.

I am trying to make a Sparse Matrix using a List of Lists method.

The first list contains elements having an X-coordinate and a list of associated Y-coordinates and values.

To find an element I iterate the list of X-coordinates to find the one I am looking for. Once found I iterate all of the associated Y-coordinates to find the right one.

Comment: Say I have a list of lists with N lists. I find the list I am looking for with a linear search taking O(N) time. The found list has M elements. I now do a linear search on that list in O(M) time.

Is the total time O(N+M)?

And what if it took O(log N) and O(log M) to find them using a binary search. Would the total time be O(log N + log M)?

Comment: @JacobOJ: Yes, exactly.  DavidK: Your answer was mislead by the fact the original poster used `n` to represent two unrelated values.

Comment: As I wrote my answer, I was wondering if I should use only N (as in the question) or if I should use M for one loop and N for the other (thereby providing a more generally useful answer). In retrospect, I think I should have used M and N, so I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, mathematically speaking, you just multiply “what's inside” the big Os. You get `O(n² log²(n))`.

Comment: Do you do that rather than substitute in the nlogn for each n which would have been my intuition...

Comment: Let's write the complexity of two algorithms `T1(n)` and `T2(n)`. With your way, their nested complexity would be `T1(T2(n))`. Let's check that. With `T1(n) = T2(n) = n` (a nested loop), you get the overall complexity: `T1(T2(n)) = T1(n) = n`. We know that a nested loop yields `n²` so your approach was wrong ;-)
*(yes, I know that technically, I just proved you way doesn't work out and* not *that mine is correct, but I'm no mathematician)*

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. My intuition was saying T1(T2(n)) but you are right that you have proved that that's rubbish. I can't think of any other options than yours but sadly I don't know that you're right so can't +1 you in all good conscience. :(

Comment: what if the function looks more like this:
  http://pastebin.com/TjR38V06
what is the time complexity on that?

It

Comment: I think the problem is that one is `n*log(n)`, and the other is `n*log(n)`, and _the two `n`s are completely unrelated to each other.  It would be more accurate to say the inner loop is `m*log(m)`, and the overall algorithm is `O(n*m*log(n)*log(m))`.

Comment: The scales are always different, you're right. It's almost *always* in terms of `n` and `m`, but the big O notation is meant to be an approximation in mathematics. Computer scientists being who they are, they approximate the approximation leading to the notation we know, and the apparent mixing of these parameters. But this notation only gives an *idea* of the runtime of a given algorithm in the worst case. IMHO, there's no need for nitpicking on these considerations, especially since it doesn't really add value. We don't write the complexity of a nested loop `n × m` after all...

Comment: @swordofpain: I disagree.  wikipedia goes over the syntax for multiple variables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables), but also mentions that it's debated, apparently mathematicians are split on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation obscures the truth, there are no "functions inside another". (More precisely, there is no function which calls another **several times**.)

What is actually done is

```
find list in n log n time;

find element in list in n log n time
```

which has complexity of order n log n.

In the second example:

```
for each element e1 in list                   // (O(N) time)  
    if e1 is the one we are looking for 
        break // Found

for each element e2 in e1                    // (O(N) time)  
    do something
```

for a total of O(N).

This is to be contrasted with true nesting:

```
for each element e1 in list                      // (O(N) passes)  
    for each element e2 in e1                    // (O(N) time)  
        do something
```

for a total of O(N²).

Comment: Your notation is also cumbersome in that it considers e1 both as an element and as a list.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. E1 is an element containing a list.

Comment: This answer was also mislead by the original poster's use of `n` for two unrelated values.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
find list in n log n time
     find element in list in n log n time
```

we get

```
Time = n log n * n log n = 2 n log n ~ O(n log n)
```

And for

```
for each element e1 in list                   // (O(N) time)  
    if e1 is the one we are looking for  
        for each element e2 in e1             // (O(N) time)  
            do something
```

we get

```
Time = n + k n = (k+1) n

Best-Case: only 1 matching value exist

Time(Best-Case) = n + 1 * n = 2n ~ n

Worst-Case: all values are identical and matching

Time(Worst-Case) = n + n * n = n + n^2 ~ n^2
```